# How can I select the row id of a table?

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a simple table of the form:

> ```
>  <table>
>  :
>  <tr class="main" id="row1"><td><a href="#" class="showstuff">Assignment 1</a></td></tr>
>  <tr class="detail hide"><td>... detail about Assignment 1...</td></tr>
>  <tr class="main" id="row2"><td><a href="#" class="showstuff">Assignment 2</a></td></tr>
>  <tr class="detail hide"><td>... detail about Assignment 2...</td></tr>
>  :
>  </table>
> ```

I want to show the detail associated with the clicked assignment, which I understand requires something of the form $(this).parent().next() to select the next row. However, I can't select the current row. In trying to debug the problem, I've tried getting the id of the current row, but just get "undefined" returned. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click",'a.showstuff',function(){toggleDetail();return false;});
});
function toggleDetail(){
 var abc = $(this).parent().attr('id');
 console.log(abc)
};
```

Where is the hole in my approach?

Thanks/B

Comment: Storing `"string"+number` values for IDs is a bad approach to begin with imo. If you have a table, chances are you should be having an array of JavaScript objects to back it up in the first place. Add the event handlers in the closure scope of those objects (or create the binding in another way) and check for the value of the JS object rather than trying to store application state on the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.parent()` will only match direct parent elements (i.e. one level up). Since you are binding your handler to the `a` elements (that are nested further down in the `td`) you will need to use `.closest()` (that will "bubble up" the whole DOM tree until its first match) instead like:

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Read the docs on [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and also do check out [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

**EDIT**:

A second issue with your code is that you lose the event handler's context when calling your `toggleDetail()` method from inside the handler. Either move your method's contents inside the handler:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.showstuff', function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
  return false;
});
```

or pass the element:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.showstuff', function(){
  toggleDetail(this);
  return false;
});

function toggleDetail(el){
  console.log($(el).closest('tr').attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks m90, but when I tried $(this).closest('tr').attr('id') I was still presented with 'undefined' in response.

Comment: In addition to that I just noticed that since you are calling the `toggleDetail` from inside the anonymous handler function `this` won't be the anchor element inside your `toggleDetail` but the `window` element that does not have an `id`, therefore it returns undefined. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/mHszj/1/

Comment: Thanks m90, your last comment was the hole I couldn't see.  Cheers/B

Answer (score 0):

The parent element of `a` tag is `td` to which you haven't given any `id` attribute. So, the result is `undefined`. You actually gave `id` to `tr` element which is two level up. you should actually do the following:

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
```